# Where can I find the definition for a system call parameter?

Tags: linux, system-calls, ioctl

In the ioctl man page it defines:

```
int ioctl(int d,int request,...);
```

For example:

```
ioctl(fd,FIONREAD,&nread);
```

Where can I find this FIONREAD information in Linux? Where is this information defined? How many types are there like this?

Comment: `man ioctl` -> `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` -> /usr/include/bits/ioctls.h -> /usr/include/asm/ioctls.h -> asm-generic/ioctls.h -> #define FIONREAD        0x541B

Answer (score 2):

In general, the man page of the system call (`man 2 ioctl` — [section 2 is for system calls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)) is the right place.

`ioctl` is a special case because the point of this system call is to allow applications to send commands to devices that don't fit in the general mold. So often the documentation of the parameters is not in the documentation of `ioctl`, but in the documentation of device drivers. Man pages for devices are in section 4 (or section 7 on some Unix variants).

On Linux, the [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) man page references [`ioctl_list(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html) which contains a summary of common ioctl types. There is more documentation about some ioctls in device man pages such as [`tty_ioctl(4)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) (terminals — that's what `FIONREAD` is used for) and [`sd(4)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html) (disks with a SCSI-like interface). More ioctl are documented in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/), for example for [CD drives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ioctl/cdrom.txt). For many drivers, Linux lacks documentation and you need to refer to the kernel source code or the headers (search under `/usr/include` and hope that you'll find comments).

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, any time you have an identifier in all caps, at least in the c language, it is usually defined in a header file somewhere.  It could be a type, an enum, or it could be an explicitly defined symbol.  Most of the time, looking in the header file is only useful to see what other possible options you have to choose from.  Using find and grep will usually locate the file (linux example):

```
cd /usr/include; find . -type f -name \*.h -print0 | xargs -0 grep <name>
```